# Unable to display contents of node from XML online

Tags: c#, xml, string, download

I have a XML document online which I'm trying to obtain and display the value of a particular node in a label.

XML:

```
<h1 class="contents-header">Upper Limit Management</h1>
<div class="contents-body">
<table class="data-table" width="500px">
 <tr>
  <th scope="col" width="165px">Max. Allowance Set</th>
  <th scope="col" width="165px">Max. Allowance</th>
  <th scope="col" width="170px">Meter Count</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Disable</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>32</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<hr class="contents-end" title="">
</div>
```

And here's the C# code I've tried to obtain and display it. I'm trying to display the node "Meter Count" which has a value of 32.

```
 private void loadxmlbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myXmlString = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://10.86.192.24/system.xml");

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); 

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Upper Limit Management/Meter Count");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            string count = xn["td"].InnerText;

            countlbl.Text = "Your current count is: " + count;
        }
    }
```

However, on the button click, nothing is happening. Is anyone able to point out what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not the same as XML, you will have to use something like a [HTML Parser](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML to XML.